# Git basic - merging old branch into master

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm working on a project that has an old branch 'new-changes'.

This branch was created weeks ago with chnages that now need to be add to master

Since the 'new-changes' branch was created lots of things have changed in master.

I now need to merge the changes in 'new-changes' into master.

If in master I do

```
git merge new-changes
```

will it just add the things in 'new-changes' or will it revert master back to the state it was in when 'new-changes' was created.

Whats the best way to add the changes in 'new-changes' back into master

Comment: You should have a look at the documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are on `master` and do `git merge my-branch`, then

1. In case of a fast forward merge (`my-branch` is ahead of `master` by certain number of commits), the commits in my-branch that are not there in master will be added to master. Existing commits in master will stay intact.
2. In case the two branches have conflicting changes, the above merge command may or may not ask you to resolve conflicts add will add the commits from `my-branch` to `master` and will create a merge commit.

> Whats the best way to add the changes in 'new-changes' back into master ?

If the branch in which you want to take changes (master in this case) is not shared and only you are going to use it, then you can either go with rebase or merge. Both have their trade offs.

If your branch is a shared one, always merge as it's the safest option. Rebasing a shared branch can give your peers nightmares when they try to resolve conflicts as rebase rewrites history.

Comment: my branch 'new-changes' is old so there will be new commits in master not in 'new-changes'

Comment: Yes. Even in that case, when you merge your branch to master, the existing new commits in master will be kept as they are and commits in your branch will be merged chronologically. So the master post merge will contain changes from both existing master and your new branch.

Answer (score 1):

If the old branch is just a local one (that is, has not been pushed to the server) I would recommend performing a [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).  This will simply apply the commits from your local branch to the tip of your master branch, without overwriting anything existing in master.